# app is stopped when I assign value to property of widget

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm a beginner in android and now practicing UI and tabbed activity.

The problem is that my code work when I don't do anything to widgets in my fragment. If I assign value to any property of a widget, my app is stopped in my smartphone with no error code, as soon as I run the app, even though there is no compile error.

I don't know why this is happening!

My code based on the form of tabbed activity project of android studio and I modified. Thank you!

```
package com.example.uiscrolled.ui.main

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.uiscrolled.R
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class SetupFragment: Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_page, container, false)
        return root
    }
}

class Dummy : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
        return root
    }
}
```

Setup_Fragment.kt

```
package com.example.uiscrolled.ui.main

import android.content.Context
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import com.example.uiscrolled.R

private val TAB_TITLES = arrayOf(
    R.string.tab_text_1,
    R.string.tab_text_2
)

class SectionsPagerAdapter(private val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return when (position) {
            0 -> Dummy()
            else -> SetupFragment()

        }
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return context.resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2
    }


}
```

SectionsPagerAdaper.kt

```
package com.example.uiscrolled

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.uiscrolled.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.setup_page.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        picker1.minValue = 0
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                  >
    <Switch
            android:text="@string/change_type_of_timers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/select_type" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:textOff="@string/개별설정" android:textOn="@string/전체설정"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" android:showText="true"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/on_lay" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker7"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:gravity="start|end" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50" android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tot_time_valve5"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve1_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tot_time_valve1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tot_time_valve2"
                android:showText="true"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve2_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tot_time_valve2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tot_time_valve1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tot_time_valve3"
                android:showText="true"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve3_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tot_time_valve3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tot_time_valve2"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" android:showText="true"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve4_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tot_time_valve4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tot_time_valve1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tot_time_valve5"
                android:showText="true"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve5_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tot_time_valve5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tot_time_valve6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tot_time_valve4" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tot_time_valve2" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                android:showText="true"
        />
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve6_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tot_time_valve6"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tot_time_valve3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tot_time_valve5" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                android:showText="true"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/off_lay" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve1_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/valve1"
                android:showText="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/valve2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:textSize="14sp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/picker1"/>
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker1"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/valve1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/picker2"
                android:gravity="start|end" android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve2_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/valve2"
                android:showText="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/valve1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/valve3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/picker2" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker2"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/picker3"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/valve2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picker1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve3_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/valve3"
                android:showText="true"
                android:textOn="@string/on" android:textOff="@string/off"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/valve2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/picker3" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker3"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/valve3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picker2" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve4_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/valve4" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/valve5" android:textOff="@string/off"
                android:textOn="@string/on" android:showText="true" android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picker1"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve5_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/valve5" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/valve4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/valve6"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                android:showText="true" android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picker2"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="@string/valve6_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/valve6" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/valve5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" android:showText="true" android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picker3"/>
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker4"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/valve4" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/picker5"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"/>
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker5"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/valve5" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picker4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/picker6"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
        <NumberPicker

                android:id="@+id/picker6"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/valve6" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picker5" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"/>
        <Button
                android:text="@string/save_button"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/save_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picker5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

setup_page.xml

```
2019-08-11 01:53:30.528 10615-10615/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-08-11 01:53:30.528 10615-10615/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2019-08-11 01:53:30.528 10615-10615/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2019-08-11 01:53:31.196 10615-10615/com.example.uiscrolled E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.uiscrolled, PID: 10615
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uiscrolled/com.example.uiscrolled.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: picker1 must not be null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: picker1 must not be null
at com.example.uiscrolled.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Red texts in logcat

Comment: Please cheack your Console while Running It will show you what Actually Error Is Thank You.

Comment: Please share your logcat. If you don't know how to check the logcat. Check this [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Comment: I added logcat, Thanks sanoJ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `picker1` variable is declared in `setup_page.xml`. But you are accessing the variable from `MainActivity` which root view is set to `activity_main.xml`. Since you didn't post the code from `activity_main` layout. I'll say set the `picker1` variable in the `SetupFragment`.

Comment: As you said, I moved the assigning code to SetupFragment. But it made the same error. After several attempts, I found that the code picker1.maxValue should be in onCreateView() and should be root.picker1.maxValue = 10. even if your answer isn't a direct solution, thanks to your answer, I solved the problem!

Comment: I should have been more elaborated. Glad you found out yourself.